# A way to not wait for JPA query result in EJB

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, ejb, fire-and-forget

i want to know if is there a way to not wait for JPA query result in ejb
i have to call a stored procedure whit JPA that make some mass complex treatements on Oracle database,
i found `javax.ejb.Asynchronous` but i don't want to create a thead for that, just call and forget the sotred procedure

Thnaks

Comment: *"but i don't want to create a thead for that"* Why exactly? Why are you shooting yourself in the foot?

Comment: because of timeout, i don't want my thread stay waiting for the PS (8hours) until it finishes

Comment: Search about Quartz Scheduler, maybe is a good option for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDBC API that JPA is typically based on is synchronous, so you cannot achieve what you want without creating a secondary thread to wait for JDBC to return. One alternative would be creating a helper stored procedure in Oracle that just schedules execution of the main stored procedure and returns immediately. Then you would invoke the helper stored procedure from Java.

Sort of:

```
create or replace procedure schedule_myjob is
begin
    -- search documentation for 
    dbms_job.submit('myjob', ....);
    -- NOTE: dbms_job.submit will not have effect until you commit
    -- your transaction. 
end schedule_myjob;

create or replace procedure myjob is
begin
   -- Your main procedure code
   ...
end myjob;
```